# Calculate percentage between two columns in SQL Query as another column

Tags: sql, percentage

I have a table with two columns, number of maximum number of places (capacity) and number of places available (availablePlaces)

I want to calculate the availablePlaces as a percentage of the capacity.

```
availablePlaces    capacity
1                  20
5                  18
4                  15
```

Desired Result:

```
availablePlaces    capacity  Percent
1                  20        5.0
5                  18        27.8
4                  15        26.7
```

Any ideas of a SELECT SQL query that will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT availablePlaces, capacity, 
       ROUND(availablePlaces * 100.0 / capacity, 1) AS Percent
FROM mytable
```

You have to multiply by 100.0 instead of 100, so as to avoid integer division. Also, you have to use [**`ROUND`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) to round to the first decimal digit.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0cc3e/1)

Comment: @missdevops Glad I was able to help. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed! Had originally done this without ROUND() and without dividing by 100.0 and was getting only zeroes and ones. Much appreciated. :-)

Comment: Your comment on multiplying by 100.0 instead of 100 was the key in my case. Thanks.

Comment: For SQL Server in SSMS, the output will show a bunch of trailing zeros because it casts this to a decimal. You have to convert it to a float to remove trailing zeros:

ROUND(CAST(availablePlaces * 100.0 / capacity as FLOAT), 1)

Comment: What if you don't tables but want to use 2 selects ? Like I have a complex select that would make avaialable places X digit, and another selects that create capacity as Y digit. how do I use it?

Answer (score 1):

The following SQL query will do this for you:

```
SELECT availablePlaces, capacity, (availablePlaces/capacity) as Percent 
from table_name;
```

Comment: This will do integer division and return either 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a number formatting function such as `format_number` (or an equivalent one in your database) to format a double as a percentage? This example is generalized. The returned value is a string.

```sql
WITH t 
AS 
( 
    SELECT count(*) AS num_rows, count(foo) as num_foo
    FROM mytable
)

SELECT *, format_number(num_foo/num_rows, '#.#%') AS pct_grade_rows
FROM t
```

This avoids the use of `round` and multiplying the numerator by 100.